# I want to create two separate columns with some spacing between them

Tags: tables, spacing, columns

How do I achieve this in Latex?

Comment: `\begin{tabular}{c@{\hspace{3cm}}c}`

Comment: Welcome. // Kindly follow an introduction like this one: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables . // Our "currency" is code, for many reasons. Next time please post your attempts, too. Thanks